# API con ASP.NET, El ejecutar un POST envia espacios en blanco

Tags: c#, asp.net, api, post, net

Hola soy bastante nuevo en esto de .net y tenia que crear una API para poder hacer un registro simple, la cree usando el sig. video
https://youtu.be/TbKuHOjRFno

El API funciona puedo hacer los GET,POST,PUT pero note que cuando hago un POST los datos se guardan con muchos espacios en blanco, ejemplo mi campo correo en la base Microsoft SQL Server solo perimite 50 espacios entonces si tu envías

"andres"

Se registrara

"andres(34 espacios en blanco)"

Con todos los espacios en blanco faltantes
Quiero suponer que como toma el modelo de la base de datos envía así, como dije nose mucho sobre .net asi que si me pueden  ayudar se los agradecería

Este es el modelo

```
    namespace ApiV2.Models
    {
        using System;
        using System.Data.Entity;
        using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
        using System.Linq;

        public partial class Modelo : DbContext
        {
            public Modelo()
                : base("name=Modelo1")
            {
            }

            public virtual DbSet<usuarios> usuarios { get; set; }

            protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
            {
                modelBuilder.Entity<usuarios>()
                    .Property(e => e.u_email)
                    .IsFixedLength();

                modelBuilder.Entity<usuarios>()
                    .Property(e => e.u_nombre)
                    .IsFixedLength();

                modelBuilder.Entity<usuarios>()
                    .Property(e => e.u_password)
                    .IsFixedLength();
            }
        }
    }

Y este el controlador

namespace ApiV2.Controllers
{
    public class usuariosController : ApiController
    {
        private Modelo db = new Modelo();

        // GET: api/usuarios
        public IQueryable<usuarios> Getusuarios()
        {
            return db.usuarios;
        }

        // GET: api/usuarios/5
        [ResponseType(typeof(usuarios))]
        public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Getusuarios(int id)
        {
            usuarios usuarios = await db.usuarios.FindAsync(id);
            if (usuarios == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return Ok(usuarios);
        }

        // PUT: api/usuarios/5
        [ResponseType(typeof(void))]
        public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Putusuarios(int id, usuarios usuarios)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return BadRequest(ModelState);
            }

            if (id != usuarios.u_id)
            {
                return BadRequest();
            }

            db.Entry(usuarios).State = EntityState.Modified;

            try
            {
                await db.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
            catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
            {
                if (!usuariosExists(id))
                {
                    return NotFound();
                }
                else
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }

            return StatusCode(HttpStatusCode.NoContent);
        }

        // POST: api/usuarios
        [ResponseType(typeof(usuarios))]
        public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Postusuarios(usuarios usuarios)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return BadRequest(ModelState);
            }

            db.usuarios.Add(usuarios);

            try
            {
                await db.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
            catch (DbUpdateException)
            {
                if (usuariosExists(usuarios.u_id))
                {
                    return Conflict();
                }
                else
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }

            return CreatedAtRoute("DefaultApi", new { id = usuarios.u_id }, usuarios);
        }

        // DELETE: api/usuarios/5
        [ResponseType(typeof(usuarios))]
        public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Deleteusuarios(int id)
        {
            usuarios usuarios = await db.usuarios.FindAsync(id);
            if (usuarios == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            db.usuarios.Remove(usuarios);
            await db.SaveChangesAsync();

            return Ok(usuarios);
        }

        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                db.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        private bool usuariosExists(int id)
        {
            return db.usuarios.Count(e => e.u_id == id) > 0;
        }
    }
}
```

No se si necesiten mas info de la base, son solo campos Varchar no tienen nada en especifico.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

rances, al estar usando  en tu modelo,  `.IsFixedLength();`le indicas que debe tener una longitud fija, en tal caso te lo rellena con espacios en blanco.

Si no quieres usar ese comportamiento simplemente quilato.

Comment: Si, era eso muchas gracias